# Image resizing using approximation

Tags: resize, approximation

I've been given a task to make image resizing using approximation. The problem is that i have no idea how may it works. The previous task was to do this using interpolation, and everything was clear about that. Now i need to use approximation. So for example if i have 512x512 picture, and let's say i take every other pixels. With this i get twice smaller picture. So now i would like to use that picture (256x256) to get back to my original one. But I have no idea how to retrieve that data using approximation. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the programming language you are working with, if any, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: This question is horribly vague. Try starting here, and see if you can find an effect which will suit whatever situation you're in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling

Comment: Well i will try to this in matlab i believe. I did nothing so far, coz i need the key to get the point of retrieving data using approximation.                                                       @Dave thanks for the link, but i do not see any approximation there, there are few interpolations

Comment: "approximation" seems to be a term which you have coined, or at least you're not giving it its full name. From your comment, it sounds like you're trying to approximate the image (or large parts of the image) using mathematical functions? If that's the case, your approach (the functions you allow your model to use) will need to be heavily tailored to the sorts of images you're working with.

Comment: Hmm.. Well i got a task to make some image smaller twice, and they enlarde it to it's original size. For this i was told to use 1 interpolation which i did (i used nearest neighbour) and 2 approximation. I do not get the point of this appriximation. I know the difference when i look at some signals but when it comes to an image i get lost. I also do not have to adjust a method to image. I just need to see the difference in the output of approximation and interpolation. When i try to google for "image resize using approximation" the output is about interpolation :D